# How to get IP adress from aws ec2 command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have tried to get instance details by using following aws command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-name, Values=index-cores"
```

However it gives output in json format. So I tried following grep on output

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-name, Values=index-cores"|grep -w "PrivateIpAddress"|sort -u
```

but still result is not as expected.

Can anyone suggest how to get single line output for each IP.

Comment: Try `jshon` http://kmkeen.com/jshon/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=XXXXXX' --output text --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]]'
```

Return IP and name of a server passed in Values, if you need public address you can play with query params.

Without filter return all ip and names of your EC2.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the IPs:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters <your-filter>
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

Output:

```
10.4.1.100
10.7.12.212
10.10.10.100
```

---

If you want the IPs in a single line comma separated:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters <your-filter>
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text | paste -sd,
```

Output:

```
10.4.1.100,10.7.12.212,10.10.10.100
```

---

If you want the IPs in a single line space separated:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters <your-filter>
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' --output text | paste -sd' '
```

Output:

```
10.4.1.100 10.7.12.212 10.10.10.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the Public IP of the ec2 instance without using the CLI is below.

From the ec2 instance run:

```
wget ipinfo.io/ip
cat ip
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work nicely:

`aws ec2 describe-instances \
--region eu-west-1 \
--instance-ids \
--query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress \
--filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=instance_name" \
--output=text`

I would double check since I have seen above examples returning `none` in results.

```
10.1.12.123
None
```